# Unit Test Framework Type

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs

The team is reporting on Unit Tests. Using the TFS API we were able to get details such as success/faulure, duration, start/end times, and other more general details.

We are attempting to get the framework of each test (ie. nUnit, MSTest, etc.) I've looked through the interfaces that are available in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client but haven't found anything of value. Is this data available anywhere? Or is there a property that has the test text where we could search for a reference for the frameworks?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: TFS 2013 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools